# How to unlink a linked-duplicate?

Tags: mesh, linked-data

All is in the question, we can duplicate object with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but also with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, which is quite handy, because as you know every changes done on a linked duplicate object will be repeated on others linked objects ("same objects").

I've used it as example to create all the UVs of a box, all at once.. But now I would like to break it, to stop it... And I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Sorry, It seems I've FINALLY found the answer, just press "U" in edit mode, and we can stop the objects from being linked.

Comment: For more recent versions of Blender, see also: [Can not find unlink object data in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128760/15265). Note there is a Unlink option in the contextual menu of the ouliner. It has [nothing to do with creating separate instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/147559/15265). Unfortunately the help just text says: Undocumented operator.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can press <kbd>U</kbd> > `Unlink Object+Data`. The object's "data" is the mesh itself. Multiple objects can use a single mesh, so that editing one will update the others (they're "Linked")
You could also go into the Object Data tab and manually select different mesh data for the object to use:

[image: Object Data chooser]

The `2` on the right indicates that that mesh is being used by two objects. Clicking on the `2`will copy that mesh and unlink that object from the old mesh, linking it to the new one (using an incremented name like `Cube.001`), the same result as if you'd done <kbd>U</kbd> > `Unlink Object+Data`

I know you already know the answer, but this is a place for the future too :)

Comment: I come from the future and this doesn't seem to work anymore, here in Blender 2.8 "U" in edit mode gives me the Unwrap menu.

Comment: So for 2.8 unlink is called "Make single user". It is in Object menu> Relations>Make single user>...