# Unlinking animation data from objects

Tags: animation

Say you create two cubes (in edit mode as the same object) and animate them, then separate the two cubes into separate objects, they both now have the same animation data.

Moving the animation markers in the dope sheet on either object changes the markers for the other object. Is there a way to unlink these objects so they can now be animated separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the objects that share the same animation and press <kbd>U</kbd>> *Object Animation*.

Alternatively, you can open the *Dope Sheet Editor*, change to the *Action Editor* view and press the number next to the action name (which represents how many objects are using the action) to make the Action a *single user*:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, spent ages trying to figure that out :D

Comment: If this has answered your question you can *accept it* by clicking the checkmark next to the question.

Comment: Done, say you also have shape key data for those objects, is there a way to unlink that data also?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/how-to-unlink-a-linked-duplicate/1900#1900

Answer (score 3):

Previous answer does not seem to be available in blender 3.2.2

Here is my workaround :
In object mode, select your object you want to separate the linked animation data, open ***Object*** menu **->** ***Relations*** **->** ***Make Single User*** **->** ***Object Animation*** or Object Data Animation

(I don't know the difference between those two)
Feel free to edit my answer or comment below if you have more info.

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought at the very least that instances were linked by their keyframes.