# Can not find unlink object data in Blender 2.8

Tags: linked-data

Currently using Blender 2.8 and I would normally hit "U" to unlink object data from  linked duplicates I can't seem to find it anymore. Searched the word "unlink" in the preferences but nothing comes up except for remove from linked collection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of the official release of Blender 2.80, 'unlinking' of objects is called 'Make Single User'.

1. Select object(s)
2. Go to the 3d viewport menu: Object-->**R**elations-->Make **S**ingle User-->Object & **D**ata
3. After selecting that menu item, a pop-up appears where you may choose **S**elected Object(s) or **A**ll

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I discovered where it was after posting this, the hotkey for unlinking object data seems to have been removed but I found it under the Object menu under Relations "Make Single User"

Comment: This did not work for me. Also, if you right-click on the mesh data of the duplicate in the outliner, and choose "Unlink" it gives the error: "Not yet implemented".

Comment: I found it using Space-Search. Object -> Relations -> Make Single User -> **Object & Data**

Answer (score 2):

I posted a [issue](https://developer.blender.org/T65495) about this to developers, but It seems that this is not considered as an issue, and just close It.

If anyone want to know How the hack is this working, I'll post my research here:

## TL;DR;

Unlink on **an object** is an alternative meaning of **Deleted**

Unlink on **a collection** is working, but If you have nested linking collections and multiple scenes, unlink a collection might affect UNKNOWN amount of scenes with that collection. The best practices for multiple scenes for now, is only unlink **ROOT** collection, so you don't need to care nested problem.

## Original

I researched for whole day and finally found out that this feature is really unintuitive to use.

First, Unlink is only working on collections, but sometimes not. How could this happen?

**If you add a collection(a) in a LINKED COLLECTION(b) that linked by before scenes (shallow copy), then change back to another scene and unlinked It(a)**, and the unexpectable tragedy happened! (a) gone for All scenes, what I expected was just unlink from certain scene.

This seems to be logical on programming, but there is NO tag (remark) on Collection that showed as LINKED, so If you had a bunch of scenes and collections mixing together (and use shallow copy), the unlink method is marked as useless to use.

I thought this feature should mark as, ex. Collection Weapon(L) or Collection Weapon(L-SceneOne). I prefer the last one, because If there is just **L**, you have no idea, where It derived from.

Or this is unexpected behavior or Bug, don't care what I'm explaining above :(

By the way, Objects unlink in difference scene is no possible to use since the Collection is linked and the algorithm is only binding Collection. For now, Unlink an object means throw It in to OrphanData (Or call It the second *Delete button*).

Answer (score 2):

A workaround:

1. With the Object you want to unlink selected, go into Edit Mode.
2. With Face Select, choose the parts of the object that you want to "Unlink".
3. Hit "P" to open the Separate dialogue.
4. Click "Selection"

You should now see a new Object in your selection in the Scene Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Si hiciste duplicados con shift D.
Selecciona el duplicado a separar.
En modo objeto, ir a objeto.
Parent
Clear parent
De esa forma el objeto duplicado queda limpio de las propiedades heredadas y se le puede editar por ejemplo el color de material.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. You might have noticed that questions and answers on this site are in English. This is intended, because it reaches the biggest possible audience. Please edit your answer and translate it into English.