# strange behavior duplicating objects in blender 2.8

Tags: add-on

Within a day of installing the molecular script addon, selecting an object in blender 2.8, duplicating it (hitting "shift + d"), and confirming (if that's the right term) the duplication (hitting "enter") results in the two objects becoming linked.  This problem is similar, but not identical, to the problem described in [Can not find unlink object data in Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128760/can-not-find-unlink-object-data-in-blender-2-8)
None of the solutions to unlink the two objects works.

A workaround: the second object is able to be moved without hitting "g", and that's enough to unlink it from the original.

The question is how to make a duplicate without having to move the copy of the original?

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a few problems. Either this is a Blender glitch, in which the answer for that case is to restart Blender, or you may have set the objects to be linked when you duplicate them. You can fix this by looking at the options Blender shows on the left when you duplicate the object. If the box shows "linked" as being checked, then click that to unset linking the objects when duplicating. Also, perhaps, it may be because you hit enter to confirm the duplication. If you left-click the mouse (or track-pad), it will also confirm the duplication's location. Right-clicking keeps the duplicated object at the first object's location, but keeps the duplication.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you provided a picture.

Comment: Nate, thank you for your prompt suggestions.

Comment: The "linked" box is not checked in the options menu associated with object duplication.  However, left-clicking the mouse did indeed confirm the duplication's location, and allowed me to keep it in the same location as the original mesh.  I will mark this issue solved, thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem. Turns out, I had “Proportional Editing” turned on. Shortcut is “B“. Turn it off. It’s a small, concentric-circles icon at the top of the viewport, next to the Snap controls.

Comment: In my experience the shortcut for proportional editing is "O" for orange. whereas "B" for betty, is box select.

Comment: I have 2.8, and keymaps set to Industry Compatible. Maybe that’s why?

Comment: Quite probable. Recommend blender default settings as much as possible for answers

Comment: This is 100% another answer to this.  It was exactly the same problem, duplicating and not being able to move separately (confirmed duplicate was created, not using duplicate linked, "linked" not checked in the duplicate settings window).  Turning off proportional editing fixed the issue.