# I want to separate a 3D model entirely

Tags: objects, edit-mode, pose-mode, dupli-groups

When you duplicate a object in Blender and make changes to the new mesh (just created) it changes the old duplicate as well.

How do you make them separate and don't affect each other? Such as changing the color.

Comment: do you want to `Unlink object data`?  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128760/can-not-find-unlink-object-data-in-blender-2-8

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/how-to-unlink-a-linked-duplicate

Comment: The standard method to duplicate objects usually is to duplicate them unlinked, which is Shift+D, but it looks like you are using Alt+D to duplicate which always produces linked duplicates.