# How Can I Unlink Two Objects?

Tags: mesh, objects, linked-data

I recently got this mouse model and want to make an Ad with it.

My Problem is that those two Parts are connected somehow.

I made them 2 Separate Objects in Edit Mode by using <kbd>P</kbd> ( Separate Object ) but if I move one, the other Object moves too.

How can I unlink those 2 Objects?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/how-to-unlink-a-linked-duplicate

Answer (score 1):

In the picture, the two parts are both selected.  If you came straight out of *Edit Mode* to *Object Mode* and then tried to move one, you will of course move both while they're both selected.

Press <kbd>A</kbd> to toggle selection until nothing is selected, then right click on the one you want to move.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, literally. There is what I found.

Please see the image. Hope this will help your issue. Select both objects first.

[image]