# What is the difference between 'Unlink' and 'Delete' in the Outliner?

Tags: outliner

[image]

I tried to use *Unlink* in Outliner, because I didn't know what it is exactly.
It seems to do the same thing as *Delete*.

But there must be differences between them. What is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Unlink* removes objects from collections, *Delete* erases them permanently.

[Removing Data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html#removing-data-blocks)

Unlinking doesn't remove the object or its geometry from the opened file, it just removes them from the collection clicked on. If an object is in more than one collection simultaneously it will still remain in others, otherwise it may become *Orphaned Data*.

**Orphan data is "garbage collected" and may be removed on saving file.**

Put [Outliner in *Orphan Data Mode*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#header) to check before saving to avoid losing any important data.

Deleting fully erases the object and its geometry immediately, while also removing it from all the collections it was in, from the scene and from the file, reducing file size and memory consumption.

[image]

Comment: thank you! your answer is perfect.

Comment: Sure of that? I mean about unlink = not removed from the file? I may have missed something.

Comment: @lemon If an unlinked object becomes an orphan, it may be lost after save and re-open.

Comment: @batFINGER, ok so we aggree about that. 'otherwise it will be unlinked from the scene and become orphaned data, but not removed from file' is not correct.

Comment: @batFINGER, seen your edit. Can 'delete' be considered as 'unlink from all'? Or is there something else?

Comment: As at this time I believe delete is equiv of `BlendDataObjects.remove(object, do_unlink=True, do_id_user=True, do_ui_user=True)`  The default being do unlink.  After running datablock is removed.  Unlink doesn't remove data block.